# ¿Como ocultar columnas en un datagridview pero pudiendo seguir usando su valor en C#?

Tags: mysql, c#, datagridview

Lo que quiero es en una consulta SQL obtener varios datos de un producto (no tengo problema realizando la consulta) dentro de los datos obtengo el ID (primera columna), no quiero mostrarlo en la tabla pero si necesito usarlo para otra funcion si se selecciona esa columna o si se hace clic. Asi es como lo tengo de momento, me sirve pero quiero ocultar esa columna.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        id_producto = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        EditarProductos editarProductos = new EditarProductos(id_producto);
        editarProductos.ShowDialog();
        LlenarListaProductos();
    }

private void LlenarListaProductos()
    {
        string proveedorID = consulta.GETidProveedor(menuProveedor.Text);
        //Buscar producto segun el elemento 0=Todos, 1=Codigo Interno, 
2=Codigo Barras, 3=Numero, 4=Modelo 5=Nombre, bool=proveedor
        bool proveedor;
        if (checkProveedor.Checked)
            proveedor = true;
        else
            proveedor = false;
        if (radioTodos.Checked)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = 
listas.ListaProductos(textBuscar.Text, 0, proveedor, proveedorID);
        else if (radioCodInt.Checked)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = 
listas.ListaProductos(textBuscar.Text, 1, proveedor, proveedorID);
        else if (radioCodBar.Checked)
            dataGridView1.DataSource = 
listas.ListaProductos(textBuscar.Text, 2, proveedor, proveedorID);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y el problema es???

Comment: Como obtienes los productos? Son Todos los productos que vas a mostrar o es uno en especifico?

Comment: Ya agregue detalles de como lo tengo funcionando, imagen y codigo, me sirve pero por cuestiones de estetica quiero ocultar la primera columna pero si necesito el valor para llamar a la otra funcion

Comment: @Adrian y te da error si ocultas la primera columna? Puedes ocultarla y dónde hagas doble click traerte el dato que necesitas de esa fila

Comment: @Nathy si, probe con `dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);` pero al momento de llamar la otra funcion me marca error, ya que ahora toma como referencia la primera columna del codigo de barras

Comment: Las columnas las generas automaticamente desde el source, o las generas a mano? si queres ocultarlas, tenes que generarlas a mano, y poner como no visible la columna que no queres que se muestre...

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por ayudarme a ubicar como es la instruccion, para ponerlo como no visible es con la siguiente instruccion, asi se oculta y sigue la misma referencia en el codigo como si ahi estuviera. No fue necesario llenar la tabla manualmente.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: El tema con esto, es que tenes que hacerlo si o si cada vez que rellenas la grilla...